# How to restrict a user if not inside a bounding box in the map

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, latitude-longitude, bounding-box

I am using a Geolocator to locate my current location.

I am trying to figure out the computation on how I can disable using a feature if you are outside the bounding box in the map.

I have this computation

```
if (x1 < x && x < x2 && y1< y && y < y2){
   log('You are inside the bounding box');
} else {
   log('You are outside the bounding box');
}
```

where;

x, y = my latitude, longitude

x1, y1 = northeast latitude, longitude

x2, y2 = southwest latitude, longitude

but this does not work well, can anyone provide me a much better solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_polyutil) you can create a custom polygon on map and detect where user is in reference to its lines. When user is outside the polygon you disable functionality.

Since you're using geolocator you can use more generic version of the package [found here](https://pub.dev/packages/poly). And use it the same way with some kind of custom marker drawn on the map with your polygon.

Comment: Thank you and also, I used this package->https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_utils